# How to add more than 20 columns in SQLite 3 for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, sqlite

I am an iPhone developer. I am using SQLite Manager (SQLite 3) on my iPhone and I have added the SQLite Manager add-on to Firefox on my Mac.

Now I need to create a table with 30 columns. However, the SQLite Manager supports the maximum of 20 columns per table. After adding 20 columns, there is no options to add more.

How can I create a table with more than 20 columns in SQLite?

Comment: What is "sqlite manager"? (post a link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do it.

> <> You can write SQL query to create db.
>
> <> You can use other SQLite tools for databse creation:   :
>   use [MesaSQLite](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mesasqlite&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGkQFjAA&url=http://download.cnet.com/MesaSQLite/3000-2065_4-166835.html&ei=cReyT9SCL8rjrAfrid2WBA&usg=AFQjCNGwOQfXXr8MXyaEClqzot_JJyTz8g&cad=rja) :it is a GUI tool with more features.

Answer (score 1):

With sqlite manager you can do this too. Initially create table with 20 columns. After that select table from left panel. On the right side you will see option to add column where you can specify Name, Type, Not Null, Default attribute of column.

Other answer is also useful but thought you may find this useful too if you are willing to use sqlite manager only.

Hope this helps.